# Clarifying the Process of Generating iid Gaussian Random Vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, covariance, gaussian, iid

This may be a silly question I just wanted to double check my understanding of random vector creation in MATLAB.

I would like to generate 100 two-dimensional iid random vectors using a gaussian distribution of mean 0 and standard deviation 1. I did this using the code

```
iid_gaussian_vectors = normrnd(0, 1, 100, 2);
```

I believe that the row vectors of the output will be my iid gaussian vectors, is this correct? I tried to check the covariance and and it is small but not exactly 0 (probably due to numerical error?). Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: All statistical estimators have a margin of error. Why would you expect the estimated covariance to be exactly zero?

Comment: I wasn't expecting exactly 0 but I was getting like -0.6 and that felt a little large for being "close" to 0.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more precise then.

Comment: Yes, your interpretation of the `normrnd` function is correct. How are you computing the covariance matrix? If you consider `iid_gaussian_vectors` to be 100 observations of the same two-dimensional distribution, the (estimated) covariance matrix is `cov(iid_gaussian_vectors)`. With that, I'm getting covariance values with absolute values smaller than 0.6; see [here](https://tio.run/##bYsxCsAgEAT7vOJKBQu1TMhbRE4TLOKF0/h9c6QOLEwxs4Q9jjznQQwMO7jV2QWglBTO@LRWYg0jYyduYivxxTUpa8DJrNDrTXoUiTTU3@8LUmm3QuWN03rJNc35Ag). They will be smaller (more accurate estimation) if you replace 100 by say 10000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, (theoretically) when you generate random samples from a Gaussian distribution (mean 0, std. dev. 1), each dimension is (or should be) perfectly independent of each other and the covariance between any two dimensions is (or should be) exactly zero. However, in practice, due to the finite precision of floating-point arithmetic used in computers, tiny numerical errors accumulate during calculations and its these errors that lead to very small non-zero values in the off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix. That's why you are seeing a very small value of covariance.

Secondly, Yes the `iid_gaussian_vectors` will indeed be a 100x2 matrix, where each row represents a random vector.

Comment: The (main) reason of non-zero covariance is not floating-point issues, it's randomness. The computed covariance is a random estimate of the true covariance. Please see my comment in the question